# uitableview data repeating when scrolled swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

After parsing JSON data, show in table view. It's working fine the first time. Table view cell had three buttons (in, out, absent). When I click any button I can call the other JSON API. After getting the data from JSON I have to update the table view and reload with new data but when click any button table view data is repeating.

[image]

How do I overcome this issue? This is the code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell =
        tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
            withIdentifier: "DetailsCell", for: indexPath) as! AttendanceDetailsTableViewCell

    let row = (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row

    if(attendanceInfo.count>0){
        cell.Class.text = attendance.standard
        cell.NameLabel.text = attendance.name
        cell.InLabel.text = attendance.inTime
        cell.OutLable.text = attendance.outTime
        return cell
    }
```

Second Data function when succeed:

```
if(errorCode == "0")
{
    self.getAttendances()
}
```

This is getAttendances() function:

```
let task = session.dataTask(with:request,completionHandler:{(d,response,error)in
        do{
            if let data = d {
                if let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
//                    print("json data ",jsonData)

                    errorCode = String(describing: jsonData["errorCode"]!)

                    msg = jsonData["msg"] as! String

                    if errorCode == "0" {
                        if let kid_list = jsonData["students"] as? NSArray {
                            for i in 0 ..< kid_list.count {
                                if let kid = kid_list[i] as? NSDictionary {
                                    if let store = kid["attendance"]  as? NSDictionary
                                    {
                                       self.attendanceInfo.append(AttendanceInfo(
                                            studentId: kid["studentId"] as? String,
                                            name:kid["studentName"] as? String,
                                            classId : kid["classId"] as? String,
                                            standard: ((kid["standard"] as? String)! + " " + (kid["section"] as? String)!),
                                            photo : (imageURL),
                                            school: kid["schoolName"] as? String,
                                            schoolId : "1",
                                            url : self.serverURL,

                                            attendanceDate: AttendanceDate,
                                            inTime : InTime,
                                            outTime: Outtime,
                                            attendance:Attendance,
                                            updatedTime:updateTime,
                                            attendanceId: AttendaceID

                                            )
                                        )                                            
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            self.do_table_refresh()
                        }
                    } else {
                        self.displayAlert("", message: msg)
                    }
                } else {
                    self.displayAlert("error")
                }
            }else {
                self.displayAlert("error")
            }
        } catch let err as NSError {
            print("JSON Error \(err)")
        }
    })

    task.resume()
}

func do_table_refresh(){
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        self.activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()

        self.TableView.reloadData()
        return
    })
}
```

Table view data is repeated after the data updated and table reloads.

Comment: Side note: You should check out `guard let` statements to improve your code. All these `if let`s and their curly braces make the code unnecessarily long and hard to read.

Comment: When you do this: `attendance.standard`, where does `attendance` come from?

Comment: The method `cellForRowAt` won't compile. Repeating unexpected data in a table view occurs if UI elements are changed in an `if` condition without adding a balancing `else` clause to assign default values.

Comment: attendance.standard comming  from JSON                                                    let attendance = attendanceInfo[row] as AttendanceInfo

Comment: JsonAPi (get-attendance) For get the student Details and pass to the Table view and second Json Api(update attendance) Update the student information. inside second json implementation I can call getattendance after getting reload the tableview but the data is repeated

Comment: Can you show me the full `cellForRowAt` method please? That is the key for this question.

Comment: @nagarajukankanala Remove all data from attendanceInfo array before adding student list into it. Write code just above of line : if errorCode == "0" { ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must clear the array before adding new data, otherwise you'll always be appending items to the end.

Add `self.attendanceInfo.removeAll()` right before it enters in your loop

`for i in 0 ..< kid_list.count {
    ...`

Comment: You're very welcome man, every last of us went through those rockie's mistakes. Keep it up! 